# OpenMP: complete first iteration first

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, openmp

I have a C parallel for loop which includes a line like

```
b[i] = b[0];
```

so I need to complete the first iteration before starting any other iteration. Is there a clause which enforces such behavior?

Comment: making 999 gpu cores wait for 1 gpu core to finish is slower than computing that in cpu i think

Comment: because you are wasting 999*(gpu power) for only 1 gpu power for the first cycle.

Comment: @tuğrul So what? Sometimes that’s unavoidable. Furthermore, it’s the same that’s happening in normal serial code. But it’s also irrelevant here, OpenMP isn’t for GPUs.

Comment: even if you have only 2- cpu cores, making other core wait could raise deadlock

Comment: @tuğrul I don’t think the term means what you think it means. Deadlocks don’t occur “just like that”.

Comment: There is no gpu involved here, only a workstation with 24 xeon cores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pull the first iteration out of the loop and start the loop at index 1. That’s by far the easiest and cheapest way. Other ways involve waiting, which is inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done, but it feels kinda "dirty". I was hoping OpenMP would provide a clause for doing this